# Data not showing - Unexpected token function

Tags: angularjs

Not sure what I have wrong but it's not showing the data in this calendar app I'm creating with angular with code academy, any ideas?

I get this error Unexpected token function in console.

day.html

```
        <h2 class="date">{{ days.date | date }}</h2>
        <div class="event" ng-repeat="event in days.events">
          <a href="#/{{$index}}">
            <h3 class="name">{{event.name}}  </h3>
            <p><span class="from"> {{event.from | date}} </span> - <span class="to"> {{event.to | date}} </span></p>
          </a>
        </div>
```

DayController.js

```
    app.controller('DayController', ['$scope', 'events', function($scope, events) {
      events.success(function(data) {
        $scope.days = data;
      });
    }]);
```

events.js

```
app.factory('events',['$http', function($http){
    return $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/events-api/events.json')
  .success(function(data){
    return data;
  })
  .error(function(err){
    return err;
  });
}]);
```

Comment: The error must point you to where the error is thrown, doesn't it help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current problem with your code is, you haven't returned `$http` promise, I meant to say you had returned it but you applied `.success` & `error` callback over that promise, which restricted your code to follow promise chain over it.

App factory code should return a promise which is already being returned by `$http.get`. Also I would say that factory should have methods so that it can be easily extended it in future.

**Factory**

```
app.factory('events',['$http', function($http){
    var events = {};
    events.getData = function(){
        return $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/events-api/events.json');
    };    
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('DayController', ['$scope', 'events', function($scope, events) {
  events.getData().then(function(response) {
    $scope.days = response.data;
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have the factory simply return $http.get

```
app.factory('events',['$http', function($http){
    return $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/events-api/events.json')
}]);
```

This will return a promise that is resolved in your controller as what you are currently doing

```
events.then(function(res) {
    $scope.days = res.data;
});
```

For a better solution, you could use resolve and inject the resolved data into your controler. checkout an example [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx)

Comment: Using `.success` & `.error` is deprecated.. & having factory in this format wouldn't provide extend-ability feature in future..

Comment: See I udpated remaining part.. do look at mine answer for the comment which I mentioned..

Comment: My answer is about the error he got. As for a better solution, I would suggest to use resolve instead of injecting the service itself.